# Make distinction between a TcpClient in c#

Tags: c#

How can I as a server make distinctions between a TcpClient that connects to me?
As a Client, do I always have to send a username or something from which the server can know who I  am?

Comment: You can send whatever you want.  It's up to you to write a server that understands what you send.

Comment: I understand, but let's say I make distinction with a username. I send  the username once, when i connect. Do I always have to send my username when I send a new message or is there another way to make distinction between them?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What problem are you having?

Comment: That really depends on your application if no more than 1 connection is issued per IP you have no needs for an identification as long as your server can limit that. regardless you could always keep a SID on the client so your server can identify it.

Comment: I need to make a server-client app for school with multiple clients. On the Client side I need to see all the clients that are connected. I know how to to that but what is unclear for me is if I get a new message from a client, how do I know which client it was? Do I always have to send my username to the server when sending a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typicly use data transmited client side to the serve to identify the client.   Identifiers i use are :

Lan and Wan ip addresses,
computername,
username,
operating system,

in addition to your comments i would like to suggest creating a client class inside the server that handles variables that have already been transmited by the client so you don't have to resend username and so on

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unique identity for each user , when he/she send a message. Means, you can use primary key id from users table or anything else(you can generate any static ID code for each user). and after login, you can use it for every message from that client.